# How to edit configmap in kubernetes and override the values from a different yaml file?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to edit the configmap and replace the values. But it should be done using a different YAML in I ll specify overriding values as part of that file.

I was trying using `kubectl edit cm -f replace.yaml` but this didn't work so i want to know the structure in which the new file should be.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: int-change-change-management-service-configurations
data:
  should_retain_native_dn: "False"
  NADC_IP: "10.11.12.13"
  NADC_USER: "omc"
  NADC_PASSWORD: "hello"
  NADC_PORT: "991"
  plan_compare_wait_time: "1"
  plan_prefix: ""
  ingress_ip: "http://10.12.13.14"
```

Now lets us assume NADC_IP should be changed and So I would like to know how should be structure of the YAML file and using which command it can be served?

The override taking place should only be during helm test for example when i run 
`helm test <release-name>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kubectl replace -f replace.yaml`

If you have a configmap in place like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
data:
  should_retain_native_dn: "False"
  NADC_IP: "10.11.12.13"
```

and you want to change the value of `NADC_IP` create a manifest file like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
data:
  should_retain_native_dn: "False"
  NADC_IP: "12.34.56.78" # the new IP
```

and run `kubectl replace -f replace.yaml`

Comment: What would be structure of that replace.yaml?

Comment: It's the manifest for the configmap you want. Your old manifest will be replaced with this new one.

Comment: Please do elaborate with example. Thanks

Comment: I've elaborated above.

Comment: But this should only run for `helm test <release-name>` how can we in corporate that here.

Comment: I seem to have misread your original question. I don't think you can do that since helm test tests a deployed release, and changing values would mean redeploying.

Comment: But this could mean that we want to change configmap only for tests not for production.

Comment: I understand, but I don't think `helm test` has a mechanism for that. you're going to have to get clever, or run a separate release for testing.

Answer (score 5):

> kubectl get cm {configmap name} -o=yaml --export > filename.yaml

You can try this it will give you yaml format

> kubectl get configmap
>   int-change-change-management-service-configurations -o yaml

You can copy the content and replace it inside new yaml file and apply the changes

**EDIT : 1**

If you want to edit over terminal you can run

> kubectl edit configmap {configmap name}

It will use `vim` editor and you can replace value from terminal using edit command.

**EDIT : 2**

> kubectl get cm {configmap name} -o=yaml --export > filename.yaml

Comment: if i use kubectl edit configmap {configmap name} the we manually have to i want to change it using file and kubectl command.

Comment: simply you can use your old yaml file update the value and run command `kubectl apply -f <file name>`

Comment: This will override the existing configmap in case of old configmap is present.

Comment: I want it to do done only when i run "helm test <release-name> what should it be extended with ?

Answer (score 3):

To update variable in configmap you need to take two steps:

First, update the value of variable:

```
kubectl create configmap <name_of_configmap> --from-literal=<var_name>=<new_value> -o yaml --dry-run | kubectl replace -f -
```

So in your case it will looks like this:

```
kubectl create configmap int-change-change-management-service-configurations --from-literal=NADC_IP=<new_value> -o yaml --dry-run | kubectl replace -f -
```

Second step, restart the pod:

```
kubectl delete pod <pod_name>
```

App will use new value from now. Let me know, if it works for you.

Comment: But this should only run for `helm test <release-name>` how can we in corporate that here.

Comment: I don't think it is feasible to achieve through `helm test` command.